# Add a property to array of object based on the existence of value in another array

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array to check with main array as,

```
const arrayToCheck = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Here is the Main array,

```
const mainArray = [ {name:'alex', code: 'c'}, 
                    {name:'jack', code: 'd'}, 
                    {name:'john', code: 'n'}, 
                    {name:'mike', code: 'l'}
                  ]
```

I want to add a status property with key of either 'enable' or 'disable' to the mainArray based on the values in arrayToCheck.

So the output should be

```
[ {name:'alex', code: 'c', status: 'enable'}, 
  {name:'jack', code: 'd', status: 'enable'}, 
  {name:'john', code: 'n', status: 'disable'}, 
  {name:'mike', code: 'l', status: 'disable'}
]
```

I have tried map and some to get the desired output but that did not work out,

Here is what i have tried,

```
const output = this.mainArray.map( (fil, i) => {
          return arrayToCheck.some( s => {
            if (s === fil.Code) {
              this.mainArray[i].Status = 'enable'
            } else {
              this.mainArray[i].Status = 'disable'
            }
          })
        });
```

Comment: You need to put the `some` call inside that `if` condition, not the other way round. (Also, you are abusing `array.map`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things there:

1. JavaScript is **case-sensitive**. `Code` and `code` are not the same property.
2. You're not returning anything from your `map` callback, so `map` isn't the right tool. If you just want to loop through, use a loop or `forEach`.
3. Use the *return value* of `some`, rather than doing the `if` within its callback. **But**, here you don't need `some`, because you can use `includes`.

Assuming you want to do what you did in your question (modify the **existing** objects, rather than creating new ones):

```js
const arrayToCheck = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const mainArray = [ {name:'alex', code: 'c'}, {name:'jack', code: 'd'}, {name:'john', code: 'n'}, {name:'mike', code: 'l'}];

mainArray.forEach(entry => {
    entry.status = arrayToCheck.includes(entry.code) ? "enable" : "disable";
});

console.log(mainArray);
```

If you wanted to create **new** objects, [Nenad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52206664/157247) shows you how to do that. But I didn't get that from your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` method with `includes` and spread syntax `...`. This solution returns **new** array of objects and doesn't modify original array.

```js
const arrayToCheck = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const mainArray = [ {name:'alex', code: 'c'}, {name:'jack', code: 'd'}, {name:'john', code: 'n'}, {name:'mike', code: 'l'}]

const result = mainArray.map(e => ({...e, status: arrayToCheck.includes(e.code) ? "enable" : "disable"}))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Suggest highlighting that the above creates **new** objects, instead of what the OP was doing (modifying existing ones).

Answer (score 1):

Here is easy to understand code:

```js
    const arrayToCheck = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const mainArray = [ {name:'alex', code: 'c'}, {name:'jack', code: 'd'}, {name:'john', code: 'n'}, {name:'mike', code: 'l'}]    
    const output = mainArray.map(obj => {
            obj.status = arrayToCheck.indexOf(obj.code) < 0 ? 'disable' : 'enable';
            return obj;
        })
    console.log(output);
```